# Cannot install Docker-Compose - Docker is installed

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, docker

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B with two 32GB SD cards. I installed Raspbian on the first card and I have played with it for a few weeks.  I installed Docker; Docker-Compose and created a few containers successfully.

I have now installed DietPi on the second SD card.  I have setup the WiFi network etc and installed Docker i.e. `docker run hello-world` works as expected.

However, I cannot install docker-compose.  I am following the instructions here step by step: https://dev.to/elalemanyo/how-to-install-docker-and-docker-compose-on-raspberry-pi-1mo.  It fails when I run this command: `sudo pip3 install docker-compose`.  The error is:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-mhdt38ts --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --extra-index-url https://www.piwheels.org/simple -- setuptools>=40.6.0 wheel "cffi>=1.12; platform_python_implementation != 'PyPy'" setuptools-rust>=0.11.4" failed with error code 1 in None
```

I have tried uninstalling Docker as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322603/how-to-remove-docker-package-from-apt-update, then start the instructions in my first link again.  I have also tried flashing the SD card and completely starting again.  What is the problem?

Comment: So the issue exists only on DietPi - perhaps dietpi is so lightweight that it doesn't include something you need

Answer (score 1):

- Docker Compose V2 is a major version bump release of Docker Compose.
- It has been completely rewritten from scratch in Golang (V1 was in Python).
- You can download Docker Compose binaries from the [release page](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) on this repository.

```
$ uname -m
aarch64

$ wget https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.2.3/docker-compose-linux-aarch64 -O docker-compose

$ chmod +x docker-compose

$ sudo mv docker-compose /usr/local/bin/

$ docker-compose version
```